# A DownThemAll equivalent for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons

I'm looking for a Chrome extension / add-on that's like DownThemAll in functionality.

Basically an add-on that will allow me to bulk download files with the same extension and/or pattern from a web page with a single click.

Does anyone know if Chrome now has such extensions?

Comment: Looking at Mendy's answer, looks like you would be better off heading back to Firefox.

Comment: @Urda: nah..I guess I will just stick with Chrome (long-time Firefox converted to Chrome). Have you tried its speed recently? It really is faster than Firefox (based on my experience).

Comment: DTA, Firebug, Weave, Greasemonkey, Better Adblocker. Nah, this developer is sticking with FireFox for a while.

Answer (score 37):

Yes there is an alternative in Chrome: [Download Master](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/download-master-free-down/laepcndcehndnjndpfjdcdgbneoimdgg).

[image]

Here are the release notes:
http://monadownloadmaster.blogspot.com/

Comment: a poor program if you want do download lots of files to the same folder (which is usually the case)

Comment: Not as slick as DownThemAll - I will just launch FF for the occasions when I need mass downloads. However, after a few tests, it works pretty well (in spite of the Chrome Store reviews suggesting otherwise).

Answer (score 24):

## Update

[Download All](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/downloadall/ajffocjdcmpgjmdfdfkdfdbkjafbkcke?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) is no longer available. [Chrono Download Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrono-download-manager/mciiogijehkdemklbdcbfkefimifhecn?hl=en) looks like a good alternative.

---

## [Download All](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/downloadall/ajffocjdcmpgjmdfdfkdfdbkjafbkcke?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)

This is very similar to Firefox' Download Them All extension.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Much better answer as of Feb-2013.  Still no DownThemAll for firefox though :(

Comment: I just installed DownloadAll (based on this post) and was initially very impressed - looks like exactly what I want. However I immediately began seeing very odd behavior. Downloads are completing but showing as incomplete, pausing without cause and unable to restart, completing but not removing their temporary .da_ file, etc. Not ready for prime time. Version 1.7.2.

Comment: As of March 2013 - this does what I want, but definitely still needs some polish.

Comment: Yes, It got a very similar look but lacks expected functionality

Comment: Not working now.. (NPAPI extension not accepted)

Comment: Download All currently not in the Chrome Store

Comment: This extension is no longer available in Chrome store.

Answer (score 20):

Currently we don't have something like that to chrome, and according to [this](http://www.downthemall.net/latest/no-google-chrome-support/) we won't going to see such add-on in the near future.

> While support for some types of extensions was added to Chrome just recently, the extension system in Chrome simply doesn’t cut it. It is only very limited in what you can do. Right now there is no way to port dTa over without loosing the majority of functionality.

Comment: @Mendy: thanks for your answer. I shall wait until one day Chrome will improve extension enough that something like dTa can be created.

Comment: @ShaChris23: (in response to the up comment, I can't comment there as I don't have enough rep) Just use them two. when you want fast browsing use Chrome. and when you want power browsing use Firefox.

Comment: Yup, I agree with you. That's what I think I will do for now. =)

Answer (score 9):

It's easy to simply download dta for firefox and then use firefox when you expressly are trying to bulk download media files.

Comment: That is also a good point.

Answer (score 9):

I've just hooked [DM-Bridge](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/lfjamigppmepikjlacjdpgjaiojdjhoj) (Windows only) to forward all downloads to Firefox, where they're picked up by Firefox's DownThemAll.

How-To:

- Install DM-Bridge
- Go to the settings page
- Select the radio for 'Custom', and use the path to your firefox installation. Don't forget the double quotes around the path, and append "--new-tab %u" to this.

In my case, it now looks like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox 4.0 Beta 9\firefox.exe" -new-tab %u
```

And voila! Using DownThemAll in Chrome: Ctrl + Alt + click a link to forward it to Firefox :)

Answer (score 4):

Chrono Download Manager

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrono-download-manager/mciiogijehkdemklbdcbfkefimifhecn
looks similar, but dont know how to save all files to **special** folder..

[image: looks like]

Answer (score 1):

I just tried GetThemAll Downloader (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/getthemall-downloader/nbkekaeindpfpcoldfckljplboolgkfm/related?hl=en), which has the highest user rating among the previous mentioned (as of September 2014).

However I didn't like it as you cant filter for file names (at least I couldn't find such an option) and the folder-layout is horrible. You cant even read complete links if they are to long since the window is too small (I used a netbook with a rather small screen though). May do if there are only few links to download, otherwise I cant recommend it due to missing filtering options and miserable layout.

Comment: As of today, this has been removed from the chrome store because it contained a malware.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Metalink Downloader: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/metalink-downloader/jnpljlobbiggcdikagmiepniibjdinap

Metalink Downloader can set 10 simultaneous connections to download from one url.