# Chrome change download numbering

Tags: command-line, google-chrome

As someone who uses the command line quite a lot, I find the numbering scheme for Chrome downloads which share the same name annoying: it names the later download `<name> (x).<extension>`, which is lousy because:

- It inserts whitespace which I have to escape
- I have to escape the parentheses

Is there some way to use file names which don't require any escaping?

Comment: It seems there was a feature request not so far from your. Maybe you can find an hint [here](http://superuser.com/questions/462008/disabling-google-chrome-download-auto-numbering-for-existing-files).

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, but they were asking about changing it to overwrite the existing file. I still want the numbering, just with different syntax.

Comment: The hint was: try to see if you can use some plug-in or add-on `;-)`.  For example in firefox it exists [DowloadThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/).  Here a __[link](http://superuser.com/questions/110157/a-downthemall-equivalent-for-chrome)__  for chrome similar ones. With downloadthemall you can custom the string for the file names, it exists the possibility to download with a single click, and if I remember well to substitute it to the default download manager. I should bet it exists for Chrome/Chromium too.